# How can I compare json field with a string value in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a field `payload` saved in a postgresql table which is json type. This type has a nested field `subcategory` which is string. Below is the output of this value:

```
=> select payload->'subcategory' from "Merchant";
           ?column?
-------------------------------
 "Food"
 null
 "AUTOMOTIVE"
 null
 "MEDICAL"
 null
 null
 "CLUB"
 "Petrol Stations"
```

However, I can't put this field in the where clause. Below query returns 0 rows. But from above output it shows there are rows whose value is `CLUB`. What is the right way to use json field in where clause?

```
=> select count(*) from "Merchant" where ("payload"->'subcategory')::text = 'CLUB';
 count
-------
     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what's wrong, I need to use `->>` in the where like `"payload"->'subcategory'`.

that because `->>` converts it to text while `->` makes it as JSONB

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the JSON contains operator `@>`:

```
select count(*) 
from "Merchant" 
where payload @> '{"subcategory": "CLUB")';
```